How to add data to a png converted to txt, with the png still being openable?
Maybe it's dumb, but I want to put some text in my .png file so that when you convert it to .txt (by changing its extension) you can read the text.
I have no idea how do this but i tried simply putting the the text before the "%png". On opening the .png paint 3D said there was an error.

How to do it properly is described here: PNG textinfo I suggest you use the keywords "Title" or "Comment". Most decoders react badly if the start of a compressed image file isn't right.

You can put a block of text in a PNG file, but it will be surrounded by unreadable data, which will appear to be garbage when displayed as text.
The PNG format has a tEXt chunk that you can insert in a PNG file, between any other chunks, but after the IHDR chunk. The data in the chunk is a keyword, e.g. Comment followed by a zero byte, and then whatever text you like.

You can use exiftool to insert a comment, if that's what you are asking:
exiftool -comment="Hi there" image.png

